# Zend_Forms Errors Decorator - remove html tags

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Error decorator input errors such way:

```
  <ul class="error">
     <li>Error message</li>
 </ul>
```

How can i remove this tags and leave only error message text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$errors = $zendForm->getErrorMessages();
```

I think this should work? Not 100% sure though I don't have time to check documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think a neat solution to the problem is to create your own custom decorator, and use it instead of the "Errors" decorator.